# Why does the "OTB - BundleToPerfectSensor" use the height value?

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, otb-applications

Why does the "BundleToPerfectSensor" use the height value?

QGIS wants to use the OTB plug-in to do Pansharpening.

I wonder why the height value is needed to convert the MS image to high resolution.
There is a selection of geoid and DEM data, and of course, there is no problem with Pansharing even if there is no height value.

I wonder how the height value is used in the "Bundle To Perfect Sensor" function.

Answer (score 1):

[BundleToPerfectSensorModel](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_BundleToPerfectSensor.html) is designed to work with Panchromatic and Multispectral images even if the input data are not aligned. If the two sensors are not aligned, then you can apply geometry corrections to both images before you can proceed with the pansharpening. There are different levels of quality of the geometric correction, and the most accurate (orthorectification) uses a DSM to take into account the deformation of the image while projecting in the same coordinate system. You can work with a DEM if you don't have an up to date DSM, or even without any, but then the absolute accuracy of the positioning could be less good (especially if you are on a rough terrain, not so much if you are on a flat one). Nevertheless, if the images are taken with very similar viewing geometry (that is, in most of the cases), the geometric correction without a DSM will commit the same errors at the same place, so the pansharpening still works well (Pan and XS images will be aligned even if the absolute position of the pixels is locally inaccurate).

Some image providers, such as Pleiade, offer already aligned images so that you can directly work in sensor geometry.